# SSH'ing to server failes after setting ipv4 rules in sysctl.conf

Tags: networking, server, ssh, vpn, ipsec

Good morning guys,

i have been trying to establish a secure connection through IPsec vpn between our server and my machine to test the VPN. i have been following this tutorial
[Site So Site Ipsec VPN](https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2018/02/11/setup-a-site-to-site-ipsec-vpn-with-strongswan-and-preshared-key-authentication/)
but in step 2:

> $ cat >> /etc/sysctl.conf << EOF
>
> echo net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
>
> net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0
>
> net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0
>
> EOF
>
> $ sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf

the guy wants us to add some ip forwarding to our sysctl.conf file but when i add it and reboot my OS (XFCE) i can no more connect to my server through SSH
when i connect it says

> connection to ip.ip.ip.ip port:22 timed out

Comment: I deleted your answer as requested. You might wan to contact SE to [merge your accounts](https://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out, when you forward some IPs, you have to do it both on the server and the PC, I only did it on the PC when I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set a private tunnel ensure your vpn config for both the servers is correct.
I think the issue is either with the firewall or your vpn configuration rather than any parameters in sysctl